ssh root@host not working despite proper config - what's missing?
I need to temporality enable root SSH in a Fedora 40 workstation with key. SSH client logs confirms that the proper key is sent and accepted (copied below). sshd debug logs (also below) show the same, but somehow ROOT LOGIN REFUSED FROM ... is still happening.
Things I've done:

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config: PermitRootLogin yes + AllowUsers root ...
DenyUsers|DenyGroups in same file not set.
root user not locked as per sudo passwd -S root, also with a valid shell.
set sudo setenforce 0 provisionally to rule out SELinux.
ls -l /root/.ssh/authorized_keys (and parent dir) confirms proper permissions (600,700) - (using StrictModes no just in case, anyway)
/etc/security/access.conf shows no restrictions for root (all lines commented)
No custom config was added under cat /etc/pam.d/

Client logs:
ssh -v -t -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey root@192.168.1.11
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:4ZMC... explicit agent
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519...
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@192.168.1.11: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Sever logs:
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "root"
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.1.23"
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: userauth_pubkey: publickey test pkalg ssh-ed25519 pkblob ED25519 SHA256:4ZMC4... [preauth]
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: fd 5 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: matching key found: ED25519 SHA256:4ZMC4....
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: Accepted key ED25519 SHA256:4ZMC4.... found at /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: Postponed publickey for root from 192.168.1.23 port 50995 ssh2 [preauth]
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey-hostbound-v00@openssh.com [preauth]
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: attempt 2 failures 0 [preauth]
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: fd 5 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: matching key found: ED25519 SHA256:4ZMC4j....
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: Accepted key ED25519 SHA256:4ZMC4jv... found at /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:1
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: auth_activate_options: setting new authentication options
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: ROOT LOGIN REFUSED FROM 192.168.1.23 port 50995
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: Failed publickey for root from 192.168.1.23 port 50995 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:4ZMC4jv....
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: debug1: auth_activate_options: setting new authentication options [preauth]
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: ROOT LOGIN REFUSED FROM 192.168.1.23 port 50995 [preauth]
Jul 25 08:37:05 n1 sshd[110058]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 192.168.1.23 port 50995 [preauth]

Also:
cat /etc/securetty                                                                                                                                                    
ssh
pts/0
pts/1
pts/2
pts/3


Check the contents of the root authorized_keys file ; possibly restriction have been added to the key you’re using

Looks like you're using the wrong key: "Failed publickey for root"

@HBruijn there are no restrictions in the authorized_keys file. It's an exact copy of the one another (non-root) user can use.

@kovshenin the key file works for another user, and we see multiple "Accepted key ED25519 SHA256:4ZMC4jv" lines in the server debug output, also a "matching key found". I'm trying to understand why despite this it's rejected later.

Did you restart sshd after setting PermitRootLogin? Seems like the "ROOT LOGIN REFUSED" is coming from here: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/b05fda224bbcd2f641254534ed2175c42487f3c8/auth.c#L369

@kovshenin WOW, that link is useful, thanks. Yes, I've restarted sshd after each change (with systemctl reload) I can't explain why the message is there.

sudo sshd -T | grep -Ev '(#|^$)' | grep -Ei 'permit' revealed that the effective configuration was permitrootlogin no despite my changes on the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
A deeper investigation revealed that the system I was working on had a /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf file overwriting this, even though that file was meant to config something different ‍♂️
